# XML: Replace all values "-1" with numbers "9", "10", "11" etc

Tags: xml, notepad++, increment

I have the following XML example:

```html
 <Song FilePath="D:\Sync\DJ\Library2\Rudimental, Ella Eyre - Waiting All Night (feat. Ella Eyre).mp3" FileSize="11720042" Flag="25165826">
  <Comment>(key shift) E7|Vm___|32b</Comment>
  <Poi Name="E6|Vm___|32b" Pos="0.831464" Num="1" Color="4280869396" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E4|Vmk__|64b" Pos="28.259464" Num="2" Color="4280869396" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E2|Vm___|64b" Pos="170.888464" Num="3" Color="4294840954" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|Vm___|32b" Pos="280.602464" Num="4" Color="4294840954" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="0.458594" Type="automix" Point="realStart" />
  <Poi Pos="11.80" Type="automix" Point="fadeStart" />
  <Poi Name="E6|Vmk__|32b" Pos="11.802812" Num="-1" Color="4294934272" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="11.802812" Type="beatgrid" />
  <Poi Pos="50.202268" Type="automix" Point="cutStart" />
  <Poi Name="E7|VmKhb|96b" Pos="50.202813" Num="-1" Color="4294902015" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|VmKhb|128b" Pos="83.202812" Num="-1" Color="4288020735" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|VmKhb|128b" Pos="127.002812" Num="-1" Color="4294902015" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="Break 1" Pos="170.885805" Type="remix" />
  <Poi Name="E6|Vmk__|64b" Pos="192.831388" Num="-1" Color="4294934272" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="End Break 1" Pos="194.209524" Type="remix" />
  <Poi Name="E7|VmKhb|64b" Pos="214.774246" Num="-1" Color="4288020735" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|VmKhb|128b" Pos="236.717103" Num="-1" Color="4294902015" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="277.687438" Type="automix" Point="cutEnd" />
  <Poi Pos="289.90" Type="automix" Point="fadeEnd" />
  <Poi Pos="291.927075" Type="automix" Point="realEnd" />
 </Song>        
 <Song FilePath="D:\Sync\DJ\Library2\Dennis Ferrer - Hey Hey (Riva Starr Paradise Garage Remix).mp3" FileSize="6295140" Flag="25165824">
  <Poi Pos="0.011610" Type="automix" Point="realStart" />
  <Poi Pos="0.011610" Type="automix" Point="fadeStart" />
  <Poi Name="E6|_m_h_|16b" Pos="0.016599" Num="1" Color="4278255360" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="7.635646" Type="beatgrid" />
  <Poi Name="E7|Vmkhb|64b" Pos="7.635646" Num="-1" Color="4288020735" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="8.587029" Type="automix" Point="cutStart" />
  <Poi Pos="10.492608" Type="automix" Point="tempoStart" />
  <Poi Name="E7|Vmkhb|96b" Pos="38.111837" Num="-1" Color="4294902015" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|_Mkhb|48b" Pos="83.826123" Num="-1" Color="4294934272" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|Vmkhb|32b" Pos="106.683266" Num="-1" Color="4288020735" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|Vmkh_|48b+E7|__kh_|16b" Pos="121.921361" Num="4" Color="4294901760" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="150.015420" Type="automix" Point="cutEnd" />
  <Poi Pos="152.150" Type="automix" Point="fadeEnd" />
  <Poi Pos="153.332971" Type="automix" Point="realEnd" />
  <Poi Name="Break 1" Pos="121.444717" Type="remix" />
  <Poi Name="End Break 1" Pos="144.777868" Type="remix" />
 </Song>
```

and I would like to replace all instances of Num="-1" with numbered values starting from 9, restarting from 9 in each instance of Song. So the result would be the following:

```html
 <Song FilePath="D:\Sync\DJ\Library2\Rudimental, Ella Eyre - Waiting All Night (feat. Ella Eyre).mp3" FileSize="11720042" Flag="25165826">
  <Comment>(key shift) E7|Vm___|32b</Comment>
  <Poi Name="E6|Vm___|32b" Pos="0.831464" Num="1" Color="4280869396" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E4|Vmk__|64b" Pos="28.259464" Num="2" Color="4280869396" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E2|Vm___|64b" Pos="170.888464" Num="3" Color="4294840954" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|Vm___|32b" Pos="280.602464" Num="4" Color="4294840954" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="0.458594" Type="automix" Point="realStart" />
  <Poi Pos="11.80" Type="automix" Point="fadeStart" />
  <Poi Name="E6|Vmk__|32b" Pos="11.802812" Num="-1" Color="4294934272" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="11.802812" Type="beatgrid" />
  <Poi Pos="50.202268" Type="automix" Point="cutStart" />
  <Poi Name="E7|VmKhb|96b" Pos="50.202813" Num="9" Color="4294902015" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|VmKhb|128b" Pos="83.202812" Num="10" Color="4288020735" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|VmKhb|128b" Pos="127.002812" Num="11" Color="4294902015" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="Break 1" Pos="170.885805" Type="remix" />
  <Poi Name="E6|Vmk__|64b" Pos="192.831388" Num="12" Color="4294934272" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="End Break 1" Pos="194.209524" Type="remix" />
  <Poi Name="E7|VmKhb|64b" Pos="214.774246" Num="13" Color="4288020735" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|VmKhb|128b" Pos="236.717103" Num="14" Color="4294902015" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="277.687438" Type="automix" Point="cutEnd" />
  <Poi Pos="289.90" Type="automix" Point="fadeEnd" />
  <Poi Pos="291.927075" Type="automix" Point="realEnd" />
 </Song>        
 <Song FilePath="D:\Sync\DJ\Library2\Dennis Ferrer - Hey Hey (Riva Starr Paradise Garage Remix).mp3" FileSize="6295140" Flag="25165824">
  <Poi Pos="0.011610" Type="automix" Point="realStart" />
  <Poi Pos="0.011610" Type="automix" Point="fadeStart" />
  <Poi Name="E6|_m_h_|16b" Pos="0.016599" Num="1" Color="4278255360" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="7.635646" Type="beatgrid" />
  <Poi Name="E7|Vmkhb|64b" Pos="7.635646" Num="9" Color="4288020735" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="8.587029" Type="automix" Point="cutStart" />
  <Poi Pos="10.492608" Type="automix" Point="tempoStart" />
  <Poi Name="E7|Vmkhb|96b" Pos="38.111837" Num="10" Color="4294902015" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|_Mkhb|48b" Pos="83.826123" Num="11" Color="4294934272" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|Vmkhb|32b" Pos="106.683266" Num="12" Color="4288020735" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="E7|Vmkh_|48b+E7|__kh_|16b" Pos="121.921361" Num="4" Color="4294901760" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Pos="150.015420" Type="automix" Point="cutEnd" />
  <Poi Pos="152.150" Type="automix" Point="fadeEnd" />
  <Poi Pos="153.332971" Type="automix" Point="realEnd" />
  <Poi Name="Break 1" Pos="121.444717" Type="remix" />
  <Poi Name="End Break 1" Pos="144.777868" Type="remix" />
 </Song>
```

I am not a developer, I would prefer a solution using RegEx in Notepad++

I am able to find the instances using Notepad++, but I do not know how to count them and replace them by incrementing values.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="Poi/@Num[.='-1']">
    <xsl:attribute name="Num">
      <xsl:number select=".." level="single" count="Poi[@Num='-1']"
         start-at="9"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Don't even think about using regular expressions for this. Wrong tool for the job.

To use with an earlier version of XSLT:

(a) replace the xsl:mode declaration with an identity template rule

(b) modify the xsl:number instruction: (i) in place of the `select` attribute, use a surrounding `xsl:for-each` to set the context item, and (ii) in place of `start-at`, capture the result in a variable and add 8 to the result.

Comment: Hi, I tried the XSL transformation. There was a bug (mismatching opening and closing xsl attributes), so I replaced </xsl:number> with </xsl:template>. I was able to run the transformation without errors, however, the result is an almost empty file, it only contains the content of the comment tags, and everything else is gone (incl all XML attributes).

Comment: Are you sure you were using an XSLT 3.0 processor? (I'll fix the typo).

Comment: I probably did not fix the typo well, because, with this version, it worked ok. I was using an online XSLT: https://xslttest.appspot.com Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Adding `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:product-version')"/>` to the stylesheet, it appears that site is running Saxon-PE 9.7.0.15, which is a bit old, but is probably reasonably conformant with XSLT 3.0 even though the site only claims to support XSLT 2.0.